# Ruby 2 intercepting request with Typhoeus

Tags: interceptor, ruby-2.2, typhoeus

I want to change query params before request is hit using [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus). What should be right approach? Do we have interceptors in Ruby as that of Java, should I be using something like before_filter as that in Rails or meta-programming in Ruby?
I just checked there is [Typhoeus::Request::Before module](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/Typhoeus/Request/Before) to hook request. Can anyone help me out how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented [typhoeus before](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/Typhoeus#before-class_method) to change query params just before request gets executed as below. Hope it helps someone.

```
require 'uri'
Typhoeus.before { |request| 
    uri = URI.parse(request.base_url)
    uri.query = [uri.query, "param1=value1"].compact.join('&') 
    request.base_url = uri.to_s
    request
}
```